# You have an error in your SQL syntax; please help :)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Can anyone help with this? Keep getting this type of error and I am totally stuck, appreciated!

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE comment_ID=`1`' at line 1

```
$wp_table = "wp_comments"; // define wordpress table name  

$gmt_offset = '-1'; // -8 for California, -5 New York, +8 Hong Kong, etc.

$min_days_old = 2; // the minimum number of days old
$max_days_old = 50; // the maximum number of days old

// connect to db
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT comment_ID FROM $wp_table") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$post_id = $l['comment_ID'];
echo "Updating: $post_id <br>";

$day = rand($min_days_old, $max_days_old);
$hour = rand(0, 23);

$new_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$day day -$hour hour") );  
$gmt_new_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$day day -$hour hour -$gmt_offset hour") );

mysql_query("UPDATE $wp_table SET comment_date='$new_date', comment_date_gmt='$gmt_new_date', WHERE comment_ID='$post_id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 

}

echo "<hr>DONE!";
```

Comment: don't use mysql_query, it is deprecated

Comment: Remove the errant comma from the `UPDATE` statement, just before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Remove the comma before `where ...` in your query

Comment: Wow, such a quick response, feel very silly now, thanks so much everyone

Comment: @LeeRitchie please move to pdo check the example in answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove comma from query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $wp_table SET comment_date='$new_date', comment_date_gmt='$gmt_new_date' WHERE comment_ID='$post_id'")
```

Comment: Providing the correct answer is great, not explaining how this is very open to SQL injections is worth the vote down.

Comment: In that case,full code is wrong because wordpress have own function for same,no need to use code php function but i am here to answer the question,not to explain how to do coding..

Comment: @BhumiShah you are here to help people and if to explain a basic thing is the case, then I believe that is why you are here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma from before your WHERE clause

Comment: Wow, such a quick response, feel very silly now, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

extra comma, before `where` updated query is below

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $wp_table 
               SET comment_date='$new_date', 
                   comment_date_gmt='$gmt_new_date' //extra Comma removed
               WHERE 
                   comment_ID='$post_id'")
```

Dont use `mysql_* api` is deprecated, in wordpress you can use `$wpdb` (here is [documentation for same](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class)), its secured. thanks Nikola for pointing out.

Comment: Providing the correct answer is great, not explaining how this is very open to SQL injections is worth the vote down.

Comment: @AresDraguna I voted down all the answer which provided the exact query which the OP can just replace, but failed to explain the SQL injection issue. Now as they have explained it, I will not upvote, but remove my downvote :-)

Comment: Actially you didn't... how about Quentin or Giwwel??

Answer (score 0):

You have a additional comma between the UPDATE-Part and the WHERE clause

Comment: Wow, such a quick response, feel very silly now, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try PDO, and secure you'r $_POST

```
$gmt_offset = '-1'; // -8 for California, -5 New York, +8 Hong Kong, etc.

$min_days_old = 2; // the minimum number of days old
$max_days_old = 50; // the maximum number of days old

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments');
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "No data";
        die();
    }
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $post_id = mysql_real_escape_string($l['comment_ID']);
        echo "Updating: $post_id <br>";

        $day  = rand($min_days_old, $max_days_old);
        $hour = rand(0, 23);

        $new_date     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$day day -$hour hour"));
        $gmt_new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$day day -$hour hour -$gmt_offset hour"));

        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE wp_comments SET `comment_date`=:ndate, `comment_date_gmt`=:gmtdate WHERE `comment_ID`=:post');
        $stmt->bindValue(':ndate', $new_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':gmtdate', $gmt_new_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':post', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```